# Intersection of two lines using general form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

How do I find the intersection of these two lines with their equations in general form. I don't want to graph them and I'm wondering if its possible with out converting them to gradient intercept form?

$2x+3y-5=0$ and $5x-y-4=0$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation, we have that $y=5x-4$. Plugging that into the first equation we get
$$0 = 2x+3y - 5 = 2x + 3(5x-4) -5 = 2x + 15x - 12 - 5 = 17x-17.$$
Solving for $x$, and then plugging into $y=5x-4$, gives the point of intersection.

Comment: @Eugene: No, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

We will label the two equations:
$$
2x +3y = 5 \qquad (1)
$$
and 
$$
5x - y = 4   \qquad (2)
$$

Multiply the second equation by $3$ to get 
$$
15 x -3y = 12 \qquad (3)
$$

By adding $(3)$ to $(1)$ we get 
$$
17x = 17.
$$
Therefore $x = 1$. Now plugging in $x = 1$ to $(2)$ we get 
$$
5 -y = 4
$$
which means
$$
- y = -1
$$
and so $y = 1$.

We check and find that it is indeed the case ie 
$$
2(1) + 3(1) = 5
$$
and
$$
5(1) - 1 = 4.
$$